# Sockjs-tornado and rpc

Tags: python, rpc, tornado, msgpack, sockjs

I'm trying to add a sockjs-tornado server to my site, and all worked fine until I decided to connect it to my other apps via MsgPack (using msgpack-rpc-python). And now works sockjs server either RPC server. Depending on wich of them start there loop first.

I think that I need to use one tornado.ioloop for both of them. But do not know how to achieve it. Or may be there is another way to add rpc to a tornado server?

Here is a sockjs-tornado sample code with msgpack-rpc-python:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

import sockjs.tornado

import msgpackrpc

class RPCServer(object):
    def sum(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """Regular HTTP handler to serve the chatroom page"""
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')

class ChatConnection(sockjs.tornado.SockJSConnection):
    """Chat connection implementation"""
    # Class level variable
    participants = set()

    def on_open(self, info):
        # Send that someone joined
        self.broadcast(self.participants, "Someone joined.")
        # Add client to the clients list
        self.participants.add(self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        # Broadcast message
        self.broadcast(self.participants, message)

    def on_close(self):
        # Remove client from the clients list and broadcast leave message
        self.participants.remove(self)
        self.broadcast(self.participants, "Someone left.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # 1. Create chat router
    ChatRouter = sockjs.tornado.SockJSRouter(ChatConnection, '/chat')

    # 1.5 Create MsgPack RPC Server
    rpc = msgpackrpc.Server(RPCServer())

    # 2. Create Tornado application
    app = tornado.web.Application(
            [(r"/", IndexHandler)] + ChatRouter.urls
    )

    # 3. Make Tornado app listen on port 5000
    app.listen(5000)

    # 3.5 Make MsgPack RPC Server listen on port 5001
    rpc.listen(msgpackrpc.Address('localhost', 5001))

    # 4. Start IOLoop
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

    # 5. Never executed 
    rpc.start()
```

`

Any suggestions or examples are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because both `start()` calls start Tornado IOLoop and they won't exit until IOLoop stopped.

Yes, you have to use one IOLoop. As `msgpackrpc.Server` accepts `Loop` class instance and `Loop` incapsulates `IOLoop`, try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    loop = msgpackrpc.Loop(io_loop)
    rpc = msgpackrpc.Server(RPCServer(), loop=loop)

    # ... sockjs-tornado initialisation. No need to call rpc.start()

    io_loop.start()
```